# jquery parent selector for label of radio input

Tags: jquery, css

My html is

```
<div id="edit-travel-mode" class="form-radios">
  <div class="form-type-radio form-item-travel-mode form-item">
     <label class="option radio" for="edit-travel-mode-0">
        <input class="form-radio" type="radio" checked="checked"   name="travel_mode">
        Round Trip
      </label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-type-radio form-item-travel-mode form-item">
     <label class="option radio" for="edit-travel-mode-0">
        <input class="form-radio" type="radio"  name="travel_mode">
        One way Trip
      </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to customize the radio box. so i add the following css:

```
input[type=radio]{
  display:none;
}
.radio_unchecked{
  some css here
}
```

i want to select the checked raido label by jquery:

```
jQuery('#edit-travel-mode input:checked').parent().addClass('radio_unchecked');
```

Do you know where is wrong? it seems that i can not add class to the label.

Comment: Are you waiting the DOM to be ready?

Comment: it looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ks2YU/1/

Comment: Seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/k3cqN/